# React: this.state is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am making a Product Display webpage using React class component, there are two parts in the page, one is Product thumbnail area(left) and the other is Big full image of the product(right), currently it looks something like this:
[image]

I want it like when the user clicks on the thumbnail the main big image should change accordingly to the same thumbnail image.

JSX

```
//React, css and all the images import

//contains all the thumbnail variable
 var thumbs = [t1, t2, t3, t4];
//Contains the Larger image in the same index order
 var model = [b1, b2, b3, b4];

export default class Display extends Component {
 
    constructor() {
        super();        
        this.state = {
        modelImage: model[0] //initially a default 1st image is to be shown
    };
  }

    render() {
        return (
       <div>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="model">
                //Thumbnails
                <div className="model-thumb">
                    {
                        // I suspect error on this line below
                        thumbs.map((thumb, index) =>
                            <img src={thumb} 
                            key={index} 
                            alt="Product-thumb" 
                            width="75px" 
                            onClick={ (index) => {
                                // Error on this line below(maybe)
                                this.setState({modelImage: model[index]}) 

                               //logs the image first time but after then always undefined
                                console.log(this.state.modelImage) 
                            }
                             } />    
                         )
                    }
                </div>
                <div className="model-image">
                    // Big Image
                    <img src={this.state.modelImage} alt="Product-image"  />
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In my search through various answers I found out this has something to do with scope, and `bind()` should be used, but I don't know the concept of `this` and scopes very much and how to implement `bind()` in my case, if that is the case please help me or suggest me the problem here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might be pleasantly surprised at how much a strategically placed `console.log(this)` can help you understand what's going on.

Comment: @Wyck yes, I got to know that atleast  the sate is being changed, but to undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onClick function for your `img` tag will not be passed an index, it will be passed an `event`. Thus, when you try `this.setState({ modelImage: model[index] })`, it's equivalent to saying `this.setState({ modelImage: undefined })`. If you remove `index` from the parentheses where you define the onClick attribute for the img tag, you should then be referring to the correct value of `index` from your `map` function:

```
//React, css and all the images import

//contains all the thumbnail variable
 var thumbs = [t1, t2, t3, t4];
//Contains the Larger image in the same index order
 var model = [b1, b2, b3, b4];
 
export default class Display extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();        
    this.state = {
        modelImage: model[0] //initially a default 1st image is to be shown
    };
}

handleClick = (index) => this.setState({ modelImage: model[index] });

render() {
    return (
   <div>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="model">
            //Thumbnails
            <div className="model-thumb">
                {
                    // I suspect error on this line below
                    thumbs.map((thumb, index) =>
                        <img src={thumb} 
                        key={index} 
                        alt="Product-thumb" 
                        width="75px" 
                        onClick={ () => { // note: removed "index" variable from these parentheses, which was really an "event"
                            this.handleClick(index) // now index passed here is the current index from the map function
                        }
                         } />    
                     )
                }
            </div>
            <div className="model-image">
                // Big Image
                <img src={this.state.modelImage} alt="Product-image"  />
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onClick={() => {
  this.setState({modelImage: model[index]})
  ...
}
```

Don't pass `index` in `onClick` method. Because you are already passing `index` in parent function (i.e. map method)

In your case `index` inside `onClick` method will be passed as event.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice the small mistake which has nothing to do with state.

Answer (score 0):

```
//React, css and all the images import

//contains all the thumbnail variable
 var thumbs = [t1, t2, t3, t4];
//Contains the Larger image in the same index order
 var model = [b1, b2, b3, b4];

export default class Display extends Component {
 
    constructor() {
        super();        
        this.state = {
        modelImage: model[0] //initially a default 1st image is to be shown
    };
  }
   handleClick(index){
       this.setState({modelImage: model[index]}, () =>{
              console.log(this.state.modelImage)  
       })   
    // in this place state don't have new value 
    // second parameter to function setState is a callback which will be call
    // after state update       
   }

    render() {
        return (
       <div>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="model">
                //Thumbnails
                <div className="model-thumb">
                    {
                        // I suspect error on this line below
                        thumbs.map((thumb, index) =>
                            <img src={thumb} 
                            key={index} 
                            alt="Product-thumb" 
                            width="75px" 
                            onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, index)} />    
                         )
                    }
                </div>
                <div className="model-image">
                    // Big Image
                    <img src={this.state.modelImage} alt="Product-image"  />
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: May I suggest that you include some text to explain what is otherwise just a _wall-of-code_ answer.  If the answer inlined in the comments, it tends to get lost without at least an introduction.

Comment: just read a litle bit about context in js. long story man.  [this](https://javascript.info/object-methods), [bind](https://javascript.info/bind)

Comment: @robert I didn't understand, and also that changed line will do nothing.

Comment: doing... binding method handle click to index and stor attach them to onClick event. you create version of handleClick witch have assignet value of index and context. whats more i told you that you can't check value of state directly after updating becasue setState is asynchronusly